# R - logistic curve plot with aggregate points

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following dataset

```
bodysize=rnorm(20,30,2) 
bodysize=sort(bodysize) 
survive=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1) 
dat=as.data.frame(cbind(bodysize,survive))
```

I'm aware that the glm plot function has several nice plots to show you the fit,
but I'd nevertheless like to create an initial plot with:

1)raw data points
2)the loigistic curve and both 
3)Predicted points 
4)and aggregate points for a number of predictor levels

```
library(Hmisc)   
plot(bodysize,survive,xlab="Body size",ylab="Probability of survival") 
g=glm(survive~bodysize,family=binomial,dat)
curve(predict(g,data.frame(bodysize=x),type="resp"),add=TRUE)
points(bodysize,fitted(g),pch=20)
```

All fine up to here.

Now I want to plot the real data survival rates for a given levels of x1

```
dat$bd<-cut2(dat$bodysize,g=5,levels.mean=T)
AggBd<-aggregate(dat$survive,by=list(dat$bd),data=dat,FUN=mean)
plot(AggBd,add=TRUE)
#Doesn't work
```

I've tried to match AggBd to the dataset used for the model and all sort of other things but I simply can't plot the two together. Is there a way around this? 
I basically want to overimpose the last plot along the same axes.

Besides this specific task I often wonder how to overimpose different plots that plot different variables but have similar scale/range on two-dimensional plots. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first column of `AggBd` is a factor, you need to convert the levels to numeric before you can add the points to the plot.

```
AggBd$size <- as.numeric (levels (AggBd$Group.1))[AggBd$Group.1]
```

to add the points to the exisiting plot, use `points`

```
points (AggBd$size, AggBd$x, pch = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are best specifying your y-axis.  Also maybe using `par(new=TRUE)`

```
plot(bodysize,survive,xlab="Body size",ylab="Probability of survival") 
g=glm(survive~bodysize,family=binomial,dat)
curve(predict(g,data.frame(bodysize=x),type="resp"),add=TRUE)
points(bodysize,fitted(g),pch=20)
#then
par(new=TRUE)
#
plot(AggBd$Group.1,AggBd$x,pch=30)
```

obviously remove or change the axis ticks to prevent overlap e.g.

```
plot(AggBd$Group.1,AggBd$x,pch=30,xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
```

giving:

[image]